# Boto3 invalid AccessToken while accessing S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to access an S3 bucket using Boto3 client with assumed role temporary credentials, and I'm getting an InvalidToken error in the process.

"The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid"

The S3 bucket is protected with a bucket policy that forces clients to assume a specific role before accessing the bucket.
The role is assumed using sts client and assume_role operation.

```py
import boto3
import uuid

sts = boto3.client('sts',
                  aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
                  aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY)

assumed_role_object = sts.assume_role(RoleArn=ROLE_ARN, RoleSessionName=uuid.uuid1().__str__())
token = assumed_role_object.get("Credentials").get("SessionToken")

session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
                       aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY,
                       aws_session_token=token,
                       region_name="us-east-1")

s3 = session.client("s3")
s3.list_objects(Bucket='my_bucket')
```

The list_objects operation gives the following error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the ListObjects operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the ListObjects operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.
```

The code is executed on jupyter notebook executing on EMR cluster.

(In code example above access kyes, role name and bucket name have been replaced with placeholders)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing incorrect access keys to your Boto3 session. You have to fetch the temporary credentials from the assumed role.

```
access_key = assumed_role_object['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
secret_access_key = assumed_role_object['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey']
session_token = assumed_role_object['Credentials']['SessionToken']

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key,
    aws_session_token=session_token,
    region_name="us-east-1"
)
```

Comment: What value is going in 'Credentials' here?

Comment: Credentials come from the assumed role.  Look in the OP's question.